# presentViewController completion block not executing

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, jasidepanels

I have a strange problem, the completion block from `presentViewController` doesn't execute lately.
This is the code called on button tap

```
    DebugViewController * x = [[DebugViewController alloc] init];
    x.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self presentViewController:x animated:YES completion:^{
        NSLog(@"Hello world %@" , self );
    }];
```

`DebugViewController` is [this class](https://github.com/gotosleep/JASidePanels/blob/master/JASidePanels/Demo/JADebugViewController.m), `self` is a `UIViewController` in a structure like this: 
`JASidepanels` ---> (center panel) `UINavigationController` ---> `self`

As expected, the exact same code works in any other project, but it isn't working in mine since a few weeks. I recently added `JASidePanels` and some other Pods.

Here is what know surely :

- the modal is presented, viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear are called, it animates in, it works correctly
- viewWillDisappear is called on presenting VC, dealloc isn't, so it is
  live.
- Other blocks work.
- It is on the main thread

Any idea how could I debug why the block doesn't execute for me ?

**Edit:** Wow, this is extremely strange. I debugged whole day and tried to delete code line-by-line. However it seems I found something really really interesting. If on any of my viewcontrollers there is a property named exactly `currentAction` (which is the case in one of my VCs), the completion blocks won't execute in the whole application ! Can someone please confirm ? Here is a gist [GIST](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b385a64f0ed57c9e7ccd), change it to `currentAction`.

Comment: Does it log if you remove `self` from the log? Also, have you set a breakpoint in there or just relying on the log?

Comment: Of course i tried with breakpoints. I tried with other instructions too, it simply doesn't enter the block... Also tried to put the block into a local variable, retain it to be sure it isn't dealloc-ed, but still nothing.

Answer (score 1):

> If on any of my viewcontrollers there is a property named exactly
>   currentAction, the completion blocks won't execute in the whole
>   application ! Can someone please confirm ?

That's probably because `UIViewController` has an instance variable called `_currentAction`, as you can see in this part of UIViewController.h:

```
id               _dimmingView;
id               _dropShadowView;

id                _currentAction;
UIStoryboard     *_storyboard;
```

Declaring a property called `currentAction` and using the default synthesis for the accessors would interfere with that ivar. To avoid that, explicitly synthesize the accessors and provide a different name for the ivar to back your property. Try adding a line like this to your class:

```
@synthesize currentAction=_myCurrentAction;
```

That *might* help you avoid interfering with the existing ivar, as long as UIViewController only accesses `_currentAction` directly and doesn't use any internally-declared accessor or KVC.

Comment: Yeah, meanwhile I saw the declaration in the header too... I will just rename my stupid variable and be happy that completion blocks do work. Yay...

Comment: I'm just curious, shouldn't the compiler be able detect situations like this ? I mean it warns me about all kinds of stupid local tableView declarations, but can't warn me if subclass property will overwrite superclass's ivar ? ...

Comment: A warning would be nice; maybe it just hasn't come up very often. You should [file a bug](http://bugreporter.apple.com) requesting that as a warning (at least).

Comment: Yea, that's what I'll do next. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Don't use alloc/init to create a view controller. Ether load it from a storyboard using `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:`, or load it from a nib using `initWithNibName:bundle:`.

That is likely the cause of your problem.

Comment: Why shouldn't you use `alloc ] init]`? If you aren't implementing a custom initializer, what's wrong with that?

Comment: `initWithNibName:bundle:` is the designated initializer for view controllers. You would need to implement loadView and create the view controller's content view yourself, through code.

Comment: Well, if you call alloc init, the designated initializer `initwithNibName:bundle:` is still called, though. I'am actually doing this for many years now, without any issues.

Comment: If I'am correct, Apple suggests to **never** call it outside of the `UIViewController`.

Comment: Yeah, `alloc] init];` will actually look for a xib file with the same name as the class and use that if it exists. This shouldn't have any effect on running the completion block in this case though.

Comment: @DuncanC I made a similar comment some time ago on another thread, and someone pointed out that `-init` is okay too. Here's part of the comment from `-initWithNibName:bundle:` in UIViewController.h: *The designated initializer. If you subclass UIViewController, you must call the super implementation of this
  method, even if you aren't using a NIB.  (As a convenience, the default init method will do this for you,
  and specify nil for both of this methods arguments.)* You learn something new every day, right? Put your feet up... you're done until tomorrow. ;-)